# I want to setup manually the 'from' advance parameter on GmailApp object, without using getAliases()

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm working on a Google Scrip to send an email using GmailApp with the basic parameters (recipient, subject, body). However, I want to use the advance parameter 'from', I'm collecting the email addresses on the spreadsheet (so I have the email from the sender), so I want to use that value on the 'from' advance parameter at the moment to send an email.

Any Ideas?. This is my current code:

```
  function formSubmitReply(e) {  
  var recipientEmail = 'test@gmail.com';
  var subjectEmail = "New User Form Request";
  //Here is where I'm using the getAliases but is not working and I already have the sender's Email on the spreadsheet
  var fromEmail = GmailApp.getAliases();
  Logger.log(fromEmail);
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  var msg = "<p>Hey IT Team</p>"+
    "<p>A request has been submitted</p></br>"+
      "<p>Test Field: "+e.values[0]+"</p></br>"+
        "<p>Test Field 2: "+e.values[1]+"</p></br>";
  if (fromEmail.length > 0){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    recipientEmail, 
    subjectEmail, 
    msg, 
    {
      from: fromEmail[0]
    });
  }else{
   GmailApp.sendEmail(
    recipientEmail, 
    subjectEmail, 
    msg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of August 2020, that is not possible but you could submit a feature request through the Google Apps Script issue tracker.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features

Comment: it's a shame that we can have more customization on this forms, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As per my testing and documentation of `from` parameter [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)), unfortunately, you cannot manually add an alias. An Alias must be one of the values returned by `getAliases()`

If by any chance you want to use aliases then you would have to add them in your Gmail settings first. You can check how to do that in one of the stack overflow answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480051/gmailapp-getaliases-returns-a-blank-list).

Comment: it doesn't make sense that we can just edit the form value **IF** we are expressing that the email addresses are being collected since the beginning, thanks!